# Java Sandbox API - Denying access in a used class

Tags: java, security, classloader, sandbox, securitymanager

I struggle a little bit with the [java-sandbox API](http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html). Consider the following code:

Sandkiste.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import net.datenwerke.sandbox.*;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxContext.AccessType;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxContext.RuntimeMode;
import net.datenwerke.sandbox.handlers.BadThreadKillHandler;

public class Sandkiste {


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Sandkiste s = new Sandkiste();
         s.run();

     }

      public void run(){
        SandboxService sandboxService = SandboxServiceImpl.getInstance();




        /* configure context */
        SandboxContext context = new SandboxContext();

        context.addClassForApplicationLoader("Test");

        context.addClassPermission(AccessType.PERMIT, "Test");
        context.addClassPermission(AccessType.PERMIT,UntrustedCode.class.getName());
        context.addClassPermission(AccessType.DENY, "java.lang.System");
        context.addClassPermission(AccessType.DENY, "java.io.PrintStream");




        context.setRunInThread(true);



        /* run code in sandbox */

        SandboxedCallResult<List<String>> result = sandboxService.runSandboxed(UntrustedCode.class, context);

        /* output result */
      }
}
```

UntrustedCode.java:

```
import java.util.List;

import net.datenwerke.sandbox.SandboxedEnvironment;

public class UntrustedCode implements SandboxedEnvironment<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> execute() throws Exception {  
        Test t = new Test();
        t.print();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Erlaubt!");
    }
}
```

I want to deny the access of the System.class in all classes which are being executed in the sandbox but
despite denying permission of the System.class the class "Test" is still able to call methods of System.  Is there are way to realize this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get `java.security.AccessControlException: No class access allowed for class: Test`. If I add `context.addClassPermission(AccessType.PERMIT, "Test");`, I get the expected behavior.

Comment: You are right. I added the missing line in. But my problem still remains: I want to give Test.class permission to run, but I still want to deny permission of the System object even if the Test.class uses it. If I run the above code I still get "Erlaubt!" as an output.

Comment: I don't, output is `java.security.AccessControlException: No class access allowed for class: java.lang.System`. Took your code, java-sandbox-0.3.jar and the recommended dependencies from their site.

Comment: commons-io-2.4.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, jsr305-2.0.1.jar, javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar

Comment: That's strange. I used the exact same configuration as you did, but sadly I still get the same result: "Erlaubt!". Could it have to do something with the Java version I am using? I am using JDK8.

Comment: I have tested with JRE5 and JRE7. I have no 8 yet on my machine.

Comment: I also tested the JRE7. Strangely it didn't work either. Could it have to do something with java or eclipse setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. The problem was that I was running this code on Windows. In Windows you have to grant all files read access. So adding the following line solved my problem.

```
context.addFilePermission(FileAccess.READ, AccessType.PERMIT, new FilePrefixPermission(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the line

```
context.addClassForApplicationLoader("Test");
```

I can only guess but it looks like it makes the `Test` class behave as not under the control of SandBox but under control of the "normal" Class Loader.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as well but then I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test exception.